# display 3 different columns from 3 different rows

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, activerecord

I have a table structured as below:

---

### leaveTypeID   |  employeeID  | balance  | status  |

1             | AT0000004    |2         |1        |
2             | AT0000004    |1         |1        |
3             | AT0000004    |3         |1        |
1             | AT0000008    |2         |1        |
2             | AT0000008    |2         |1        |
3             | AT0000008    |2         |1        |

This is the table schema:

---

**leaveTypeID**(PK) | **employeeID**(PK) | balance | status |

---

Now I want to to display in my view 
Leave Balance of AT000004 as:

**CL: 2
SL: 1
EL: 3**

Comment: Where do you want to get the values `EL`, `SL` and `EL` from?

Comment: @mapek : Those are the leaveTypes in my leaveType table which serves as a lookup table. In leaveType table the leaveTypeID alone serves as the primary key

Comment: @mapek: I dont think that has anything to do with my question. bcos I can do this <para tag> EL : (balance of at000004 with leaveTypeID )  . But my question is how to display only with values of column balance in my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this example:

**Your Model:**

```
public function modelFucntion(){
    $this->db->select('leaveTypeID,balance');
    $this->db->from('table');
    $this->db->where('employeeID','AT0000004');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**Your Controller:**

```
$data['result'] = $this->model_yourModel->modelFucntion(); // calling function.
$this->load->view('viewHTML', $data); // load view
```

**Your View:**

```
if(count($result) > 0){
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        if($value['leaveTypeID'] == 1){
            echo "CL : ".$value['balance'];
        }
        if($value['leaveTypeID'] == 2){
            echo "SL : ".$value['balance'];
        }
        if($value['leaveTypeID'] == 3){
            echo "EL : ".$value['balance'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome Sir :) Thanks a Lot. I must admit you saved a lot of my time. Hugely Appreciated.

Comment: @Hithesh: glad to help u friend.

Comment: How can i get the same value in my controller , to be used in my update function. similar to  if($value['leaveTypeID'] == 1){
            echo "CL : ".$value['balance'];
        }  and if($value['leaveTypeID'] == 3){
            echo "EL : ".$value['balance'];
        }

Comment: @Hithesh: by using this:    foreach ($data['result'] as $key => $value) { .... same code ..

Comment: Im very new to all this . But can i use foreach in my controller function. just to make it more clear , I want the balance of leaveTypeID=1 as $cl ,balance of leaveTypeID=2 as $el and so on. i want these value for further manipulation in my controller

Comment: Your really great. You have a magical touch to things. Thanks a lot once again :)

Comment: @Hithesh: keep it up bro.